# azure webjob- timerTrigger: Get current execution context?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-triggered, azure-webjobs-continuous, timer-trigger

I have written a azure webjob which has timerTrigger. The static method gets called every minute and it has to make http POST request. I want to access the appSettings.json file within the timerTrigger static method. How can I access it?

I see examples where static method for QueueTrigger have ExecutionContext and TextWriter as parameters. Please see below example:

```
    public static void ProcessOrder(
    [QueueTrigger("orders")] Order order,
    TextWriter log,
    ExecutionContext context)
{
    log.WriteLine("InvocationId: {0}", context.InvocationId);
}
```

How can I inject similar current execution context and TextWriter logger into my timerTrigger static method - "TimerTick"?
Below is my TimerTrigger static method :

```
        public class Test
        {
            private static IConfiguration _config;
            private static IHttpHandler _httpHandler;
            public Test(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpHandler httpHandler)
            {
                _config = configuration;
                _httpHandler = httpHandler;
            }

      [Singleton]
            public static void TimerTick([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer)
            {
                string baseUrl = _config?.GetSection("WebJobConfiguration:url")?.Value;
                string API = _config.GetSection("WebJobConfiguration:API")?.Value;
                Console.WriteLine("URL: " + baseUrl + API);
                _httpHandler.PostAsync(baseUrl + API, null);
            }
}
```

=======================================================================
Updating the question:

I updated the method which has TimerTrigger to be:

```
public async static Task TriggerNotification([TimerTrigger("%Job%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ExecutionContext context)
    {....}
```

Reading the %Job% from config file using NameResolver.

When I try to pass the current execution context within TriggerNotification method, I get the following error:
[image]

How can I solve this?

The webjob is configured using HostBuilder. Below is the code. I'm using Azure webjob version 3.0.3.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(SetupConfiguration)
                    .ConfigureLogging(SetupLogging)
                    .ConfigureServices(SetupServices)
                    .ConfigureWebJobs(webJobConfiguration =>
                    {
                        webJobConfiguration.AddTimers();
                        webJobConfiguration.AddAzureStorageCoreServices(); 
                    })
                    .UseSerilog()
                .Build();
            builder.Run();
        } catch { ... }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

> I want to access the appSettings.json file within the timerTrigger
>   static method. How can I access it?

I used `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` to implement it, in most situation we use this package to configure settings in Json . And I tried it could be used to read json. And here is complete code. You could have a try.

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo timer,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Doing some timely work ...");
        IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = BuildConfiguration();
        string connectString= configurationRoot.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["AzureWebJobsDashboard"];
        logger.LogInformation(connectString);


        // and other stuff .....
    }

    private static IConfigurationRoot BuildConfiguration()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = builder.Build();
        return configurationRoot;
    }
```

And you could show it in Logger.
[image]

As for `ExecutionContext`, you could refer to this [wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function), or you could go to official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#usecore), it has examples about how to use it.

Hope this could help you , if you still have other questions, please let me know.

**Update : The Program.cs pic.**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. I added "ExecutionContext context" parameter in TimerTrigger method and never seems to work. I get an error. Can you please help me with how I can access executionContext within timerTrigger?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check the code sample I have posted below the delimiter "==="

Comment: @user2439903, I tested the code and get the same code, then I found I miss something in Program.cs. You add config.UseCore();  then it will work. I will update the pic in my answer.

Comment: @user2439903, any problem now? If my answer works, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I am using webjob 3.0.3 and can't find a method in hostBuilder which has UseCore(). I have updated the question with code snippet. Can you please tell me what is missing?

Comment: @user2439903, it's not about webjob 3.0.3, method, it's in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions, you could find its description in this official doc.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#usecore And you could find ExecutionContext is defined in this binding. But it binds to JobHostConfiguration and I don't find it's defined in HostBuilder.

Comment: @user2439903, and i found in this answer config.UseXXX extension methods migrated to IHostBuilder builder.AddXXX methods. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1871#issuecomment-432347037Maybe you could try with it.

Comment: @user2439903 , you could add AddExecutionContextBinding ib the hostbuilder. Check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#executioncontext